# Triangles Update in Mesh - SharpDX

Tags: sharpdx

I'm working with SharpDX C# libraries for DirectX11. I'm following the "Direct3D Rendering Cookbook" to load an external mesh. I need to find intersections between that mesh and a particular ray but here comes the problem. If I load the mesh and then do some operations on the World matrix (translation/rotation) the Triangles list of that mesh, which I use to compute the intersections, is not updated consequently.

Comment: You need to post an example of the code that is giving you trouble. Point out where in the code the result is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to deal with ray cast intersection with the original model is fairly straightforward.  I will though assume you have a matrix for transformation of the model into the world.  What you need to do is create an inverse of this matrix and multiply the ray cast start and end by this matrix.  This gives you the ray in the local space of the model (the untransformed version of the model).   You then can call your ray cast function to get an accurate location hit.  It's one of those unwritten tricks, don't move the model, move the ray, its cheaper and faster to do.